# Find k such that two vectors are linearly dependent

Tags: solution-verification, vector-spaces, vectors, parametric

I have to find k such that:
$v=(k-5,12-k,7)$ and $w=(k+1,k-6,4-k)$ are linearly dependent.
I have found that $A=\begin{bmatrix}k-5  &12-k &7\\ k+1 &k-6 &4-k
\end{bmatrix}$ has rank  always equal to 2. (I have verified that: the three minors of order 2 are invertible)

Then I have to conclude that they are surely linearly independent?
I am not sure of this since the excercise ask to find k.

Comment: I want to pick a nit.  One shouldn't say that these two vectors are linearly dependent.  One should say that *the set consisting of* these two vectors is linearly dependent.

Comment: Indeed, but this set is dependent... of what? This is an oddity of english language. French is more consistent: we say that some vectors are (linearly) independent/dependent (implicitely: of each other!). Hence for a set of vectors we use a different word: it is free/bound.

Comment: jin, you said you have check that *the three* minors of order 2 are invertible. This is not true. However, at least one of them is, which is sufficient. So your conclusion is correct.